# LayoutConstraint added but frame is not changed

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

Look at the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
[view addConstraint:heightConstraint];

NSLog(@"view : %@", view);

}
```

And the info printed out to be:

```
<UIView: 0x7ae4c1b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae4e790>>
```

The frame is not changed to be 30 as I set up with the constraint. Why? How to make it work?

Comment: I think you need to add this view to a superview before you'll see the correct frame (and you'll probably need to call layoutIfNeeded on that superview first). BTW, the second attribute in your constraint should be NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute,  not NSLayoutAttributeHeight.

Comment: I have tried add this view to a superview. But the result remain the same. What`s more, the program will crash when setting the second attribute as NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute. The crash info is "+[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Unknown layout attribute" @rdelmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to add the view to a superview first, and call layoutIfNeeded on that superview. I don't know why you had trouble with NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute, it works fine for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
    [view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"view : %@", view);
}
```

When I run this, the log gives me this result,

```
2014-10-23 22:05:07.701 FrameTest[4293:1869985] view : <UIView: 0x7b724d40; frame = (0 0; 0 30); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b720760>>
```

Comment: I find out I miss the code : " [self.view layoutIfNeeded];"